# Decrypt or prevent Teslacrypt

Tags: encryption, file-system, decryption

Has anyone come up with a method to prevent receiving Teslacrypt or a method to decrypt encrypted files?

Is there a way to prevent encryption on network attached storage?

Is email the main avenue that Teslacrypt takes to get to end-users?

Is there a way to stop encryption files from getting through email?

TeslaCrypt is a variant of CryptoWall 1,2, and 3. It is also a varaint of Cryptolocker.

What is the difference between CryptoWall 1 through 3 and Cryptolocker?

This is not just concerning the transferring of data through a network. I am also curious how to stop it spreading through flash storage i.e flash drives and external hard drives.

Some end-users are not aware of social engineering. How can security procedures prevent end-users from getting infected? Is it best to place a list of signs of social engineering for end-users to follow?

Comment: *"prevent receiving Teslacrypt"* - Don't have write access to anything important.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CryptoWall 3 - how to prevent and how to decrypt?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80861/cryptowall-3-how-to-prevent-and-how-to-decrypt)

Answer (score 1):

The only prevention is the attention: don't click random links, don't open fake emails. Social engineering is the best attack vector for ransomwares